# PgAgent (on windows) doesn't run job

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgagent

Note: This is a new installation of pgAgent following tutorials and other info that I found over the web.
Note2: Server pgAgent is running and (apparently) without errors.

After configuring the job it never start to run, nor manually or scheduled.

Actual configuration:
[image: Job Configuration]
.

The job step is simple: run a function that exports data, but I'm not getting to that point yet, because the Job never starts.

Comment: News to this: I've installed it in another Windows Server (with postgresql 8.4 also) and I can not get it working. I'm assuming that this is an issue with the version release or something else. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I have postgresql 9.3.3 running

the mistake I did that throghrouly messed me up was running the pgagent.sql file
before actually doing the install.

follow this guide - its incredible - kudos to the writer:
http://orbitphreak.blogspot.ca/2013/04/installing-pgagent-33-on-centos-5x-x8664.html

My OS is redhat, and using pgadmin v. 1.18 (which means that pgagent comes as separately).

Comment: I've sorted out this using the Task Scheduler of Windows and running the binary pgsql from command line (from a batch file). It's not the standard way to do it, but its the only way that I found that works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that agent couldn't authorize to database so after I've made all connections trusted from localhost the service started successfully and job works fine
for more information about error you should see into windows event viewer or equivalent in UNIX based system
[image]